# Add a Button Column to a DataGridView and apply conditional text only to the button clicked

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events, datagridview

In a DataGridView, can we handle the button text change in the row level?   Only the clicked buttons have to change the text to '**Clicked**', other buttons on remaining rows keeps default text.

I added one instance of the button and add that to the grid, like below:

```
var button = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
{
    button.Name = "statusButton";
    button.HeaderText = "Button";
    button.Text = "Click to register";
    button.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;  
    this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add(button);
}
```

but when I handle the name change in the  `private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)` event all the buttons were changed the text to 'Clicked'.

Do I need to have the `n` number of buttons created for the `n` number of rows?

Comment: Can you share the code of `dataGridView1_CellContentClick` event?

Comment: See the Remarks section of [DataGridViewButtonColumn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewbuttoncolumn.usecolumntextforbuttonvalue). With `.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true`, you're specifying that the Button.Text is the same for all Buttons in the Column.

Comment: @jimi, my button text is showing the values as expected, and I can change other columns' values too. Just the button value is unable to change per row.  If change it changes for all rows of the grid.
I suspect maybe I just have only one button object and I manipulate that. Do i need to have new buttons for every rows in the grid ? - this is my concern

Answer (score 3):

As describe in the documentation, the [UseColumnTextForButtonValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewbuttoncolumn.usecolumntextforbuttonvalue) is used to specify that all Buttons of a `DataGridViewButtonColumn` will use the same Text, as specified in the `Text` property of the Column's template.

If you need to specify a different text for each button and change it at run-time, you need to set this property to `false` (or don't set it, since `false` is the default).
In this case, the [FormattedValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.formattedvalue) of the Cell is used for the Text.

Since you're adding the Column at run-time, you may not have a corresponding value in the DataSource (the Column is not bound to the source of data).
In this case, the `Cell.Value` will be `null`, so the `FormattedValue` property will return an empty string and your Buttons will show an empty text.

To set a default value, you can then set the Column's `DefaultCellStyle.NullValue` to a predefined string, which will then used as the Text for the Buttons.

```
var buttonColumn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn() {
    Name = "statusButton",
    HeaderText = "Button",
    UseColumnTextForButtonValue = false,
    DefaultCellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle() {
        NullValue = "Click Me"
    }
};
this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add(buttonColumn);
```

Then you can change the text of a single Button Cell, set a new Value and, eventually, compare this value with the `[Cell].OwningColumn.DefaultCellStyle.NullValue`, if you want, e.g., to re-set it:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex] is DataGridViewButtonCell cell) {
        if (cell.Value == null || cell.Value == cell.OwningColumn.DefaultCellStyle.NullValue) {
            cell.Value = "Clicked";
        }
        else {
            cell.Value = cell.OwningColumn.DefaultCellStyle.NullValue;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: DataGridViewButtonColumn custom text]

There are different ways to do the same thing, this is a simple and direct method, it should allow you to solve the current issue.

Comment: appreciate your efforts @jimi. out of curiosity I was trying to set the button 'Enable' & 'Disable', but don't find that option in the DataGridViewButtonColumn.

Comment: [How to: Disable Buttons in a Button Column in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/disable-buttons-in-a-button-column-in-the-datagrid)