# Show/Hide a Button in a DataGridView based on a condition

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a Column in my data source named `Status`. Based on this field, I want to change the Button's text:

For example, if `Status` is:

1. `Stop`, change the Button's text to `Start`
2. `Start`, change the Button's text to `Stop`

Please review what I have tried .

This how I bind the grid and create the `DataGridViewButtonColumn`:

```
var tasks = await TaskDetail.GetSelectedProjectTask(id);
var taskList = new BindingList<TaskDetailListModel>(tasks);
grdTask.DataSource = taskList;

var btnStart = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
btnStart.Name = "btnAction";
btnStart.HeaderText = "Start";
btnStart.Text = "Start";
btnStart.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
grdTask.Columns.Add(btnStart);
```

I want that before the data is displayed in the grid, the Button's text  should be renamed according to the value of the `Status` Column:

```
private void grdTask_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    var row = (TaskDetailListModel)grdTask.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem;
    if (row.Status == TasksStatus.Start.ToString())
    {
        var btnStop = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
        btnStop.Name = "btnStop";
        btnStop.HeaderText = "Stop";
        btnStop.Text = "Stop";
        btnStop.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
        grdTask.Columns.Add(btnStop);
    }
    else
    {
        var btnStart = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
        btnStart.Name = "btnStart";
        btnStart.HeaderText = "Start";
        btnStart.Text = "Start";
        btnStart.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
        grdTask.Columns.Add(btnStart);
    }
}
```

But it is not working as expected...
Also please review the attached [Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgsQS.png) to have clear understanding of my problem.

Comment: The grid’s `CellFormatting` event will fire often, like when the user scrolls the grid. I am confident you do not want to “add” the button column “EACH” time a cell is formatted. From what I can tell it appears the code only needs to add the button column “once” after the data is loaded into the grid. Then possibly change a button’s text if the “Status” field changes. In that case the grid’s `CellValueChanged` may be a good place to change the buttons start/stop text if the “Status” changes.

Comment: @JohnG Thank you for response
Yes, This will occure when value changed, It works for me, But what if i want to change the button text when data is binding ?

Comment: What are you using as a `DataSource` to the grid? I am guessing a `List<TaskDetailListModel>` or `BindingList<>.` It is unclear how you want this work. There is a `ButtonColumn` that displays text in the button that is the “opposite” of the “Status” field… i.e., either “Start or Stop.” Therefore, if the user clicks the button, you want to “do” something? Like change the value of the “Status” field? And if the user “changes” the Status field, you want the button to change also? This sounds odd and appears to me that a single button or combo box column would accomplish the same thing.

Comment: @JohnG please review the code once and desciption also. i have edited the code.

Comment: What is supposed to happen if the user “clicks” the button? It makes little sense to simply swap the start/stop text values for the button and “Status” field. IMO, a better approach (for the user) would be to set the “Status” column as a `ComboBoxColumn` with the two choices, “Start” and “Stop.” The button column you have seems unnecessary. Instead of clicking the button column to change the status field, the user simply changes the “Status” field directly. Adding the button column is confusing to me and I assume I may be missing something here.

Comment: You could also use a single button column for the “Status” column and “toggle” the Start/Stop values. I would think either (single column) approach would be more user friendly than simply adding a redundant button column. Without more context, speculation is all we can offer.

Comment: [Add a Button Column to a DataGridView and apply conditional text only to the button clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66625193/7444103)

Comment: @Jimi Thank you
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/disable-buttons-in-a-button-column-in-the-datagrid?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

This is what i want

Comment: Do you want to create a Button that can look like it's disabled or change its Text? If the latter, follow the simple example I posted. Otherwise, clarify your intentions.